# String.Format Для массива

Tags: c#, list, format

Есть массив

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "1", "4", "6" };
var sss = string.Format("c0={0}&c1={1}&c2={2}", list[0], list[1], list[2]));
```

Как в цикле вставить элементы из списка в переменные?

Answer (score 2):

Ну держите:

```
string.Join("&", list.Select((s, i) => string.Format("c{0}={1}", i, s)));
```

Очень похоже на построение URI. В этом случае так:

```
string.Join("&", list.Select((s, i) => string.Format("c{0}={1}", i, WebUtility.UrlEncode(s))));
```

Если это вам поможет. И если я вас правильно понял.